# better to use perl or unix commands to parse this string

Tags: perl, unix

Is there a good unix one liner or perl liner that can format this string from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><org.apache.Summary length="200429142" fileCount="197184" dirCount="50" quota="-1" spaceUsed="601287428" spaceQuota="-1"/>
```

To:

```
length=200429142
filecount=197184
dirCount=50
quota=-1
spaceUsed=601287428
spaceQuota=-1
```

Comment: probably. what do you have so far, what have you tried? (why one line?)

Comment: i would venture and try and write a perl script. being a newbie would open a fh, read it, do a split..or something like that, but i'm sure that's overkill.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a one-liner, broken up into separate lines for clarity:

```
perl -MXML::Simple -l \
    -e '$a = XMLin shift; print "$_=$a->{$_}" for ' \
    -e 'qw(length fileCount dirCount quota spaceUsed spaceQuota)' \
    (your XML string here)
```

This requires that you have the `XML::Simple` module installed.

Comment: How about XML::Parser? Can that module be used too?

Answer (score 3):

Just a fast shot: What about this?

```
sed -r 's/.*<org.apache.Summary\s+([^>]+)>/\1/' | tr " " "\n"
```

Comment: yup! that work for the most part. just need to strip the surrounding double quotes. man, i've got to learn 'sed`

Answer (score 2):

```
 sed -e 's/.*Summary //;s/\/.*$//' temp|perl -p -e 's/ /\n/g'

length="200429142"
fileCount="197184"
dirCount="50"
quota="-1"
spaceUsed="601287428"
spaceQuota="-1"
```

if you want to do in place :

```
sed -e 's/.*Summary //;s/\/.*$//' temp|perl -pi -e 's/ /\n/g'
```

if you donot need the `"` then:

```
 sed -e 's/.*Summary //;s/\/.*$//' temp|perl -p -e 's/ /\n/g;s/\"//g'
length=200429142
fileCount=197184
dirCount=50
quota=-1
spaceUsed=601287428
spaceQuota=-1
```

Answer (score 1):

A refined version based on @bmk

```
sed -r 's/<\?.?*\?>//' | sed -r 's/<[a-z\.]+//I' | \
sed -r 's/\/>//' | sed -r 's/ ([a-z]+)="(-?[0-9]+)"/\1=\2\n/Ig'
```

Total 4 `sed` were used.

1. remove the `<?xml?>`
2. remove the `<org.apache.Summary`
3. remove the `/>`
4. extract the XML attributes into pairs.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

```
perl -0777 -E'given(<>){/\?>/g; say "$1$2" while /(\w+=)"(.*?)"/g}' myfile.xml
```

**output**

```
length=200429142
fileCount=197184
dirCount=50
quota=-1
spaceUsed=601287428
spaceQuota=-1
```